# Pointcut referring to all methods with name starting by

Tags: java, spring, aop, aspect

I was trying to implement an easy pointcut expression inside my code, this is my Aspect class

```
@Aspect
public class PaymentAspect {
    
    @Autowired
    private OrdineService ordineService;
    
    @Pointcut("execution(* *..createPayment*(..))")  
    public void toVerifyCart() {} 
      
    @Before("toVerifyCart()")
    public void validateCart(JoinPoint jp) throws ServiceException, TokenStreamException {
    
         //Instructions...
    }
}
```

And this is the one of the methods before which I would like to call the validateCart() method...

```
public String createPayment(@RequestData(paramaterName = "httpRequest") Long cartID,
        String currency, String appContext, 
        @RequestData(paramaterName = "httpRequest") HttpServletRequest request) throws ServiceException;
```

The only problem is that my code is not calling at all the method... Is there anything I'm getting wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One important thing which you're missing here is `@Configuration`. You can have a `@Component` only for enable the class as a candidate component, but for `@Aspect`, you better have it annotated with `@Configuration`.

Comment: I'm answering now and although I had already posted the answer I'm going to set this as the correct answer for any future visitors with the same problem! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try with `@Pointcut("execution(* createPayment*(..))")`

Answer (score 0):

My bad, apparently @Aspect does not implies the fact that it's a Spring component so all I had to do is add the @Component on top of the class